# nurtured it to growth - how do you understand this?

Tags: meaning

> I must also mention my marvelous Greek teachers who first planted the seed of love for this language and **nurtured it to growth**.

What does that exactly mean? Does it mean that they cared for it until it reached a certain development stage where it continued to grow but on its own and the teachers' help was no longer necessary?

Comment: I think your idea sounds about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is pretty much accurate; I'd just like to add that *nurture* and *grow* are two words often linked together in English. When I hear those two words together, the first thing I typically think of is young plants, and the second thing is young children.

The language in your quote is a bit metaphorical, of course. There is no physical "seed" for the love of language; however, once the author used the word "seed" metaphorically, it's only natural that the metaphor would be continued with *nurture* and *growth*. In the context of plants, *nurture* often means *water, fertilize, and prune as needed*. In the context of instruction, *nurture* means *teach, guide, and stimulate interest*. Also, because the seed is for the **love** of the language, *growth* would refer to a growth in both knowledge and passion.